# not able to access statefulset headless service from kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I have created a headless statefull service in kubernates. and cassandra db is running fine.

```
PS C:\> .\kubectl.exe get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE  
cassandra    None         <none>        9042/TCP   50m  
kubernetes   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    6d


PS C:\> .\kubectl.exe get pods  
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE  
cassandra-0   1/1       Running   0          49m  
cassandra-1   1/1       Running   0          48m  
cassandra-2   1/1       Running   0          48m
```

I am running all this on minikube. From my laptop i am trying to connect to 192.168.99.100:9402 using a java program. But it is not able to connect.

Comment: can you post this command output `kubectl get svc cassandra`?

Comment: PS C:\> .\kubectl.exe get svc cassandra  
NAME        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE  
cassandra   None         <none>        9042/TCP   10h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your service not defined with NodePort. can you change service type to `NodePort` and test it.

when we define svc to NodePort we should get two port number for the service.

Comment: Agreed it worked. Only problem is i wanted to make it as a headless service.